# When do we know that $\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} f(x) \in f(\mathbb{R})$? And is there a argsup function or something equivalent?

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Suppose we have a function $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to A$ where $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is bounded from above. Then we know $\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} f(x)$ exists. My questions are:

- Which other assumptions do we need to know that $\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} f(x) \in f(\mathbb{R})$
- And how can we denote the element $x \in \mathbb{R}$ which corresponds to the supremum. Is there some sort of argsup function?

Comment: For the latter, you have the argsup which is the argument of the supremum. You have to define it carefully though, as you might have multiple points satisfying this property, so in general
$ \mathrm{arg sup}_{\mathbb{R}} f$ is an ensemble rather than a real number. Depending on the context, you might for instance denote by arg sup the smallest element of this set.

Comment: Note that for a general function $f(\mathbb{R})$ could be any subset of $\mathbb R$. So the condition that $\sup_{x\in \mathbb R} f(x) \in f(\mathbb R)$ is equivalent to $f(\mathbb R)$ being some set that contains its supremum. I suppose checking closed-ness of $f(\mathbb R)$ would be a 'nice' sufficient condition, but is certainly not necessary.

Comment: How to you know the set (or ensemble as you call it) has a smallest element?